# test for the file related function in python

Tags: python, file, testing

I am rather new to software testing. I wonder how to write a unit test for file related functions in python. e.g., if I have a file copy function as follows.

```
def copy_file (self):   
    if not os.path.isdir(dest_path):
        os.makedirs(dest_path)
    try:
        shutil.copy2(src_path, dest_path)
    except IOError as e:
        print e
```

What should I do about testing above function? what should I assert (directory, file content, exceptions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on shutil.copy2 copying the contents correctly. You only need to test *your* code. In this case that it creates the directories if they don't exist, and that it swallows IOErrors.

And don't forget to clean up. ;)

Comment: hi, Lennart, thank you for your input. But I am still not quite clear about what to assert. do you mean to assert the error thrown equals to IOError? sorry i do not have much experience on unit testing. Thanks again.

Comment: You assert that things are as they should be. Whatever that is. "assert" is just an English word meaning "make sure". :) I think you are overcomplicating things. (And the IOError is swallowed, so your method will never throw that.)

Comment: That is the point, exception are swallowed. As you said, probably I overcomplicated things and there is nothing to test. But as I have little experience, I really need other opinions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @pepero: There *is* something to test. As I said above: **Test that the function creates the directories if they don't exist, and that it swallows IOErrors**. I don't really know what is unclear with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can get some clue from [test_shutil](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/test/test_shutil.py?view=markup) itself and see how it is testing the copy functionality. Namely it is moving files and testing if it exists using another module.  The difference in behavior of standard shutil.copy to your wrapper is in dealing with destination if it not already exists. In shutil.copy2, if the destination not already exists, then a file is created which is move from the source, in your case, it is not file, but a destination directory is created and you move your source into that. So write tests there destination does not exists and ensure that after your wrapper runs, the destination is still a directory and and it contains the file that shutil moved.

Comment: hi, Senthil, thanks for your valuable input. I will take a reference on it.

Answer (score 0):

Think about requirements you put on your method, like:

- The method shall report an error in case source_dir does not exist or either source or destination director are not accessible
- The method shall report create destination_dir if it does not exist and report an error if destination dir cannot be created
- The method shall report an error if either source or destination dir have illegal values (`null` or illegal chars for directories)
- The method shall copy all files from source to destination directory

  - check, if all files have been copied
- The method shall replace existing files (*maybe*)

  - check, if existing files are replaced

Those are just some thoughts. Don't put any possible requirement and don't test too much, keep in mind what want to do with this method. If it's private or only used in your own code, you can reduce the scope, but if you provide a public API, then you have to make sure that any input has a *defined* result (which may be an error message).